# how can i migrate my js code to reactjs and call it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello everybody i'm a newbie so please forgive me for my silly questions i had 
a js function in angular that let me scroll horizontally two divs simultaneously

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.settActivityAndTaskCells();
    //-------------------Begin Scroll-------------------
    var isSyncingLeftScroll = false;
    var isSyncingRightScroll = false;
    var leftDiv = document.getElementById('top');
    var rightDiv = document.getElementById('bot');

    leftDiv.onscroll = function () {
      if (!isSyncingLeftScroll) {
        isSyncingRightScroll = true;
        rightDiv.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
      }
      isSyncingLeftScroll = false;
    }

    rightDiv.onscroll = function () {
      if (!isSyncingRightScroll) {
        isSyncingLeftScroll = true;
        leftDiv.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
      }
      isSyncingRightScroll = false;
    }
    //-------------------End Scroll-------------------
  }
```

so i change it like this on reactjs

```
Scrolling = () => {
    var isSyncingLeftScroll = false,
      isSyncingRightScroll = false,
      leftDiv = document.getElementById('top'),
      rightDiv = document.getElementById('bot');

    if (!isSyncingLeftScroll) {
      isSyncingRightScroll = true;
      rightDiv.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
    }
    isSyncingLeftScroll = false;

    if (!isSyncingRightScroll) {
      isSyncingLeftScroll = true;
      leftDiv.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
    }
    isSyncingRightScroll = false;

  }
```

and call it in the the div like

but the scroll doesn't work Thanks to anyone who takes time to help me, review and give feedback.

Comment: Your missing the most important part! You are not binding the function to the `scroll` event: `leftDiv.onscroll = function () {...}`

Comment: how can you edit my code? so i can understand !

Answer (score 1):

Your migration code is missing the most important part, binding the new functions to the `scroll` events. Should be:

```
Scrolling = () => {
    var isSyncingLeftScroll = false,
        isSyncingRightScroll = false,
        leftDiv = document.getElementById('top'),
        rightDiv = document.getElementById('bot');

    leftDiv.onscroll = () => {
        if (!isSyncingLeftScroll) {
            isSyncingRightScroll = true;
            rightDiv.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
        }
        isSyncingLeftScroll = false;
    };

    rightDiv.onscroll = () => {
        if (!isSyncingRightScroll) {
            isSyncingLeftScroll = true;
            leftDiv.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
        }
        isSyncingRightScroll = false;
    };
}
```

Comment: i did copy and past the code the scroll is not blocked anymore but they are not synchronized it dont work ;( we call those nested functions?

Comment: I can't be of much more help without more code. I would need to see this full component, where the divs are rendered and the flow of how you expect this to work.

Comment: i dont have something special two divs 

 <div className="divun" id="top" ref="elem"><p>heyheyheyheyheyheyhey</p></div>
<div className="divdeux" id="bot" onScroll={this.Scrolling}><p>heyheyheyheyheyheyhey</p></div>

divdeux got the horizontal scroll when i scroll it the divun scroll with it simultaneously thats it and the code was working on angular

Comment: this is and example https://codepen.io/livingston/pen/WxLAmk?editors=1010 but i want my code to work not this i'm using scroll left in the place of scroll top

Comment: I know what you want, but it seems like it's an issue with your specific setup. If you can create a codepen with your actual code, then we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: the problem that i'm new i dont know how to a codepen i just want to know if is there a problem when i called the function

Comment: Sorry, I can't help without a working example. Hope what I have provided so far gets you on the right track.